# How to make my enemies shoot in Kilibolt?

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse

Hi there I did the tutorial "creating an Android Game" at Kilibolt.com
and I completed the whole game... and changed some stuff around. Unfortunately in the tutorial they only showed how to make the main character shoot.

I have three robots that are painted, created, and are contained in an array list. I want to make them shoot randomly every few seconds or so. I tried following all of the same techniques and procedures that were shown making the MAIN CHARACTER shoot.

1) creating an arraylist of projectiles class in the MAIN CHARACTER CLASS (however for my enemies... I did it in their class)
2) Made Getters and Setters
3) Painted the array JUST as they had with the MAIN CHARACTER in my "main-startingclass"
4) and either removed or updated items in array

None of this worked for some reason. I even tried setting COMMA as a key press... then running shoot() in my enemy class... as they had with the MAIN CHARACTER. That didnt help.

I keep getting "Null Pointer Exception".... I dont know what this means or how to fix it nor am I very experienced with Java, Android, or Eclipse. Please help if you have anything that might help my situation it would be greatly appreciated.

```
SOME OF THE ERRORS`enter code here`: 
"Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kiloboltgame.StartingClass.run(StartingClass.java:213)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kiloboltgame.StartingClass.paint(StartingClass.java:310)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)"
```

Comment: What is the code on line 310, inside StartingClass's `paint()`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iaiSCqtQ

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < enemy.getProjectiles().size(); i++){
   Projectile q = (Projectile) enemy.getProjectiles().get(i);
   g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   g.fillRect(q.getX(), q.getY(), 10, 5);
   
   
  }

Comment: It'd be better if you ask this in KiloBolt Forum first as you're following and using their tutorial. As for your `NullPointerException`, probably `q` is `null`. And please, don't write meaningless comment to ping someone.